# weird characters in ciphertext

Tags: encryption

This is a ciphertext :

§ƒÜì ©©”Ñªÿƒ_G¢4Ø{i§çÞ“./

when I put this ciphertext here in this site :

http://www.charactercountonline.com/

some others 4 weird characters were shown : one character after the / and two characters between the ì and the © and one character between ¢ and 4

what are those characters ?

do they belong to the ciphertext ? should they be included , in the decryption process , with the other characters ?  or they do not belong to the ciphertext and therefore they can be ignored  and deleted ?

Comment: For most ciphers in actual use, ciphertext consists of arbitrary-looking bits. How these bits map to bytes and then characters is a computer/programming problem (awfully dependent on context), and out of the scope of cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ciphertext is an array of bytes. When you store the ciphertext in a file and open the file with an application (e.g. a text editor), the application will try to interpret the bytes in a way it understands. So in your case, the ciphertext is interpreted as textual data encoded in unicode. Some characters in unicode are not printable, so they are not displayed. When you copy the bytes into another application, the new application may interpret them in another way. Thus you see something different.

Whatever you see (or cannot see) belongs to the ciphertext. When you decrypt, feeds all bytes to the decryption algorithm. Don't delete or ignore any of them, otherwise you may not get the correct result back.